# Как в Python 3 получить icmp пакет

Tags: python, icmp

Пишу сканер портов на python, нужно получить icmp пакет для определения типа и кода, как это сделать на windows? пишу следующий код, но приходит IP заголовок и UDP пакет

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP) as sniffer:
    sniffer.bind((host, 0))
    sniffer.settimeout(3)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
        try:

            sock.sendto(b'', (host, port))
            data = sniffer.recv(1024)

            a = struct.unpack("!BBHHH", data)
            print(a)
        except Exception as e:
            self.port_dict.append(port)
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В параметре `proto` в таком случае нужно указывать `socket.IPPROTO_ICMP`, а не `socket.IPPROTO_IP`.

На всякий случай советую посмотреть [официальную документацию](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket). Там нет ничего про ICMP, зато есть много чего другого интересного.

Если нужны примеры с ICMP, вот пара примеров:

- несколько примеров в [статье на programcreek](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/50985/socket.IPPROTO_ICMP);
- небольшой пример в [официальной рассылке python-list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-December/616466.html).

Comment: Не помогло, все ваши решения подходят для linux

Comment: Жаль. Пробовал вариант [отсюда](http://bt3gl.github.io/black-hat-python-building-a-udp-scanner.html)? Там отдельно описан случай с Windows.

Comment: Ранее находил похожее и заработало) все равно спасибо)